# Spark-Submit - Scala Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I managed to build my scala spark kafka streaming jar with maven clean package

The below error occurred when I am executing spark-submit:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@368d5c00 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
        at com.huawei.bigdata.spark.examples.KafkaToOBS$.createContext(KafkaToOBS-test1.scala:30)
        at com.huawei.bigdata.spark.examples.KafkaToOBS$.main(KafkaToOBS-test1.scala:22)
```

My scala scripts:

```
    package com.huawei.bigdata.spark.examples

import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._

import java.time.{Instant, LocalDateTime, ZoneId}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

/**
  * Consumes messages from one or more topics in Kafka.
  * <checkPointDir> is the Spark Streaming checkpoint directory.
  * <brokers> is for bootstrapping and the producer will only use it for getting metadata
  * <topics> is a list of one or more kafka topics to consume from
  * <batchTime> is the Spark Streaming batch duration in seconds.
  */
object KafkaToOBS {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val ssc = createContext(args)   # (KafkaToOBS-test1.scala:22)

    //The Streaming system starts.
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

  def createContext(args : Array[String]) : StreamingContext = {
    val Array(checkPointDir, brokers, topics, batchTime, groupId, path) = args   #(KafkaToOBS-test1.scala:30)
    
    // Create a Streaming startup environment.
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaToOBS")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(batchTime.toLong))

    //Configure the CheckPoint directory for the Streaming.
    //This parameter is mandatory because of existence of the window concept.
    ssc.checkpoint(checkPointDir)

    // Get the list of topic used by kafka
    val topicArr = topics.split(",")
    val topicSet = topicArr.toSet
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> brokers,
      "value.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
      "key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
      "group.id" -> groupId,
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest"
    );

    val locationStrategy = LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
    val consumerStrategy = ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topicSet, kafkaParams)

    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    // Receive data from the Kafka and generate the corresponding DStream
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, locationStrategy, consumerStrategy)

   val tranData = stream.map(x=>(x.value(),""))

    tranData.repartition(1).foreachRDD(result=>{
      result.saveAsHadoopFile(path, classOf[String], classOf[String],classOf[RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat])
    })
    ssc
  }
 class RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat  extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any]{

    def coverTimeStampToString(time:Long): String ={
      val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      format.format(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(time),ZoneId.systemDefault()))
    }

    override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String):String ={
      val timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
      coverTimeStampToString(timeStamp)
      val ymd=getDay(timeStamp)
      val hour=getHour(timeStamp)
      val service_date="day="+ymd+"/"+"hour="+hour+"/"+name+"_"+getMinute(timeStamp)//Writing path: test\streaming\day=2020-07-10\hour=17\part-00000_26
      service_date
    }

    def getHour(time:Long): String ={
      coverTimeStampToString(time).substring(11,13)
    }

    def getDay(time:Long): String ={
      coverTimeStampToString(time).substring(0,10)
    }

    def getMinute(time:Long): String ={
      coverTimeStampToString(time).substring(14,16)
    }
  }
}
```

My spark submit script:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 3 --class com.huawei.bigdata.spark.examples.KafkaToOBS --jars $(files= /opt/client/Spark2x/spark/jars/*.jar),SparkStreamingKafka010Example-1.0.jar hdfs://hacluster/tmp/ 192.xxx.x.xx:9092 DemoPOC 10 groupaaa obs://sg-demo-poc/KafkaToOBS/
```

I guess the issue is due to the 6 arguments (i.e. checkPointDir, brokers, topics, batchTime, groupId, path) have mismatch in pattern, but I don't have a clue how to troubleshoot to find out. Anyone can share a thought? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`args` is already an array. Index it, don't try to be fancy and pass it through another Array

BTW, `--jars` needs to be before `--class`. Debug by printing out the args before you "match it"...